# P2P Video in iOS + Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, opentok

What would be the best way to realize p2p video (no audio) streaming between 2 iOS clients in real time? This would need to be inside of a Unity3D (or perhaps Cocos3D) game engine.

I've looked at some WebRTC based solutions like Icelink and OpenTok, but I don't have much experience with these technologies. Can someone recommend any de facto solutions for this type of task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Opentok webrtc-based platform to enable video (and audio) communication between two or more peers.

Opentok has native SDKs for Android and iOS so it should work for you since you are working in iOS.

In order to use it from another SDK such as Unity3d or Cocos3d, Opentok exposes the sent and received video frames (RGB or YUV) to the client, so you can take that video frame image data and render it any view inside the game engine using, for example, OpenGL.

As everything is implemented in the SDK and supported by Opentok platform, enabling the video communication is a matter of interacting with the SDKs so it shouldn't be so hard.